# Running a another task when an uberjar is created with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When the uberjar is created, I also need to run lein deps. How do I make Leiningen automatically run lein deps when lein uberjar is run?

Answer (score 0):

`lein deps` is run automatically on other `lein` tasks like run jar cljsbuild...

In fact I never use `lein deps`except in `lein do clean, deps`.

Note : I am just transitioning to [`boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) myself, but composing tasks is much easier with this build tool.

Comment: When I run lein deps, lein-npm downloads npm modules, when I run lein uberjar, these modules are not downloaded. I need to trigger lein deps to download npm modules when building the uberjar is run. This is not happening automatically in my neither on machine nor in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can have leiningen run a combination of any lein tasks via the `do` command. We can then define an alias to run the desired tasks with ease. In your profile.clj include the following:

```
:aliases {"build-with-deps" ["do" "clean" "deps" "uberjar"]}
```

Then whenever you call `lein build-with-deps` it will actually run the following: `lein do clean, deps, uberjar`.

I recommend reading through the sample [project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L204) provided by leiningen to better familiarize yourself with the capabilities of aliases.